# SpringBoot how to get full URL of application

Tags: spring-boot, logging

Basically, I want to log everything that happens in the life cycle of my SpringBoot REST API, and I'd like to log something like `App started at [ip]:[port]/[everything else]`

I had already seen a question like this but it was using the embedded Tomcat, I use another web server, can it be done? It would be real cool.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve these informations using the `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` in your Controller :

```java
URI currentUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri()
                .build()
                .toUri();
String asString = currentUri.toString(); // "http://localhost:8080/orders/1/items/18"
String host = currentUri.getHost(); // "localhost"
int port = currentUri.getPort(); // 8080
String path = currentUri.getPath(); // "/orders/1/items/18"
```

Comment: tried it, it says No current ServletRequestAttributes, I want to now this informations on startup, without the need of a request being sent

Comment: Ok I tought you want to log when a request is sent to you application.

Comment: I already did that with an interceptor